# CSS selector to exclude a grandchild element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do you NOT select the nth child of the nth child of an element in CSS?

```
<div class="myclass">Root Div
    <div>1st Child
        <div>Child of 1st Child</div>
    </div>
    <div>2nd Child</div>
</div>
```

What is the selector so class `myclass` is not applied to

```
<div>Child of 1st Child</div>
```

Comment: The same way you **not select** any other element and have since the advent of CSS--by specifying an overriding rule for that particular case. CSS selectors do not "unselect"--as their name implies, they "select".

Comment: Please do not repost questions. When your question is marked as a duplicate, edit your question instead of reposting.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the HTML you have as-is, a better approach may be to apply styles to *all* divs, then override those styles for the nested div you want to target:

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
div {
  background-color: aqua;
}
div.myclass > div:first-child > div:first-child {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="myclass">Root Div
  <div>1st Child
    <div>Child of 1st Child</div>
  </div>
  <div>2nd Child</div>
</div>
```